# Not null value needed in all the column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have records coming like as in picture

Query is not working :

```
SELECT 
    'Business_Details' AS 'Business Phone','Business Email'
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TELCOM_NAME, TELCOM_ADDRESS 
     FROM 
         [mi_s_data].[dbo].[TEMP_MOS_CONTACT] 
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(TELCOM_ADDRESS)
FOR TELCOM_NAME IN ('Business_Phone','Business_Email')
) AS PivotTable;
```

I need one SQL server query which can give output like shown in this picture: [image]

Comment: Your sample data has four columns but three column names.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Select ...
case when alias1.TELCOM_ADDRESS is null
     then (select alias2.TELCOM_ADDRESS
           from [mi_s_data].[dbo].[TEMP_MOS_CONTACT]) alias2
           where alias1.Contact_id=alias2.Contact_id
           and alias2.TELCOM_ADDRESS is not null)
          )
     else alias1.TELCOM_ADDRESS
     end as  TELCOM_ADDRESS
from [mi_s_data].[dbo].[TEMP_MOS_CONTACT]) alias1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to take a look on how to [properly format an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using conditional aggregation:

```
select contact_id,
       max(case when telcom_name = 'Business Phone' then telcom_address end) as business_phone,
       max(case when telcom_name = 'Business Email' then telcom_address end) as business_email
from mi_s_data.dbo.temp_mos_contact tmc
group by contact_id;
```